# Update WPF GUi while Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, parallel-processing

I Have a WPF multithread application, and each thread updates some variables of objects binding to the xaml gui.

If I Use a normal thread or a threadpool it works fine. Each object is being updated at real time in the GUI when the object  variables is changed by the treads.

I want to use `Parallel.ForEach` because it stops the execution util all threads are finished. This is important to me for block the interface (because the use should wait), and for can show a finished message. The bad thing is that with Parallel.Foreach is not being updated in real time, only when all threads are finished.

This way works, but It only updates the Gui at the end.

```
Parallel.ForEach(Computers, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1}, computer => { PingTemp(computer); });
```

This way works, but It doesn't wait to the end of the ThreadPool.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Parallel.ForEach<Computer>(Computers, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }, computer => PingTemp(computer)));
```

What approach do you recommend when the GUI is updated in realtime and wait the execution of threadpool before continue.

Comment: I havenot used WPF for a long time but as I remember WPF window have something called Dispatcher you can use it to modify UI from other threads using BeginInfoke method passing anonymous actions like () => { someControl.Text = "new text"; }

Comment: @EOG won't work because the dispather needs the UI thread to be free (as it dispatches TO this thread) and he blocks this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do NOT do that in the same thread. If you need the user to wait, then use a mechanism where you LOGICALLY stop interaction at the UI (turn if ff, put a transparent label with a working animation on top of the window) and do things outside the loop. The whole UI interaction is blocked as long as your thread blocks.

YOu do NOT get ANY updates in the UI while the UI thread is blocking. So, that already kills what you want. But more important - you really make bad things. ALWAYS keep the UI free.

My old rule is 0.1/1. Everything longer than 0.1 seconds MUST go into a non-ui thread, anything longer than 1 second MUST disable the UI and show a working animation, preferably one that shows progress if feasible by any mreans.

I use a GUI framework that handles that automatically via bound method signatures (telling the UI this method call is async, then the routine is automatically called in a separate thread).

Comment: I have a datagrid biding to a observable collection, the objects have to strings a computer name and a result. This app do pings ans save the result in the string result that is a column bindeg in the datagrid. I want this table updated dynamically for each row (each machine) as the results come.

If this is not the right Approch @TomTom, how should I do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: WHat I said. Make it in a separate thread. Block the UI while this is running. DO NOT NEVER EVER block the UI thread more than 0.1 seconds.

Comment: But I Want the use to see the progress in the interface at real time. Can you show me an example or a link where I can fin more information please?

Comment: What part of "logically block it" is hard to understand? I never said "make it invisible". Put a transparent element in top that "swallows all user interaction. Come on, this is trainee stuff. Disable all user interaction that you don't want at this moment, leave the rest working.

Comment: Undestood. I can acoomplish this using  this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/58836/Using-Background-Process-in-WPF. Thank you TomTom

Comment: You an uaccomplish this using programming. Always nice to see people forgetting the basics.

Comment: Caliburn Micro, available on Codeplex.